# fuelphp oil migrate allow field to be null

Tags: fuelphp

Is it possible to pass an argument to Oil that will allow the new table field to be null?

something like

```
oil g migration foo bar:string null baz:int
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Of course it is possible to parse most of the parameters used to created table in generating migration. Parameters required must be separated by colon like below:

```
oil g migration foo bar:string:null baz:int:unsigned
```

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is "No".

What you are supposed to do is create your migrations using the allowed syntax and then edit the migration files located in

```
app/migrations.
```

After you have updated the migration file you can

```
run oil refine migrate
```

Comment: Just in case others find it useful, to fix the migration you add `'null' => true` to the `array` that defines the characteristics of the  table field